# How to change the status of a boolean with Callbacks from radiobuttons in matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, variables, callback, radio-button

I created a small example program to demonstrate my problem (The variable "option1selcted" does not change its value):

```
classdef radioexample < handle
    %radioexample2 
    % example for radiobuttuns
      properties(Hidden)
          % all elements of the GUI are properties of the class trechner
          formMain;   % "The MainWindow"
          menuFile;   % "The Menu Header"
          % buttons
          buttonTest
          % radio items
          radiogroup
          radio1
          radio2
          % statis variable
          option1selcted = true;
      end
      methods(Hidden)
          function obj = radioexample 
              % Constructor Form Main
              obj.formMain = figure('position',[400,400,600,260],'Visible','off'); 
              set(obj.formMain,'Name','Rradioexample','NumberTitle','off',...
                  'MenuBar','none','Resize','Off');
              % a menu for exit the program            
              obj.menuFile.main = uimenu('Label','File');            
              obj.menuFile.exit = uimenu(obj.menuFile.main,...
                  'Label','Exit','Callback',{@obj.close_Callback,obj});
              % radiobutton to select the mode
              obj.radiogroup = uibuttongroup(obj.formMain,...
                  'Visible','on',...
                  'Units','pixels',...
                  'BackGroundColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8],...
                  'Position',[220 80 100 100]);
                  %'SelectionChangedFcn',@obj.bselection);
              uicontrol(obj.radiogroup,...
                  'Style',...
                  'radiobutton',...
                  'BackGroundColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8],...
                  'String','Option 1',...
                  'Position',[10 70 70 20],...
                  'Callback',@obj.opt1_Callback,...
                  'HandleVisibility','off');
              uicontrol(obj.radiogroup,...
                  'Style',...
                  'radiobutton',...
                  'BackGroundColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8],...
                  'String','Option 2',...
                  'Position',[10 50 70 20],...
                  'Callback',@obj.opt2_Callback,...
                  'HandleVisibility','off');    
              obj.buttonTest = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Print radiostaus intop the Command Window',...
                  'Position',[40,200,260,60],...
                  'Callback',{@obj.test_Callback,obj,'test'},'Enable','On');
              set(obj.formMain,'Visible','on');
              fprintf('programm started');
          end
      end
      methods(Static,Access=private)            
          function close_Callback(~,~,obj)  
              % close window
              close(obj.f)
          end
          function opt1_Callback(hObject, evt)
              fprintf('switched to radio1 mode\n');
              obj.option1selcted = true;  %<- does not change the variable? 
          end
          function opt2_Callback(hObject, evt)
              fprintf('switched to radio2 mode\n');
              %msgbox('switched to radio2 mode','Success');
              obj.option1selcted = false;  %<- does not change the variable?
          end
          function test_Callback(~,~,obj,val)
              fprintf('the status of the radiobutton is: %d\n', obj.option1selcted);
          end     
      end
      methods(Access=public,Hidden)
          function disp(obj)
          end
      end
  end
```

To test the status of the variable "option1selcted" the testbutton writes its status into the matlab command window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change values of `obj` within a static method. Define the callback-functions within a non-static methods-block. You need to add another `~` for the input arguments. I fixed this issue in the callback of the button as well.

*Here is the full code:*

```
classdef radioexample < handle
    %radioexample2 
    % example for radiobuttuns
      properties(Hidden)
          % all elements of the GUI are properties of the class trechner
          formMain;   % "The MainWindow"
          menuFile;   % "The Menu Header"
          % buttons
          buttonTest
          % radio items
          radiogroup
          radio1
          radio2
          % statis variable
          option1selcted = true;
      end
      methods(Hidden)
          function obj = radioexample 
              % Constructor Form Main
              obj.formMain = figure('position',[400,400,600,260],'Visible','off'); 
              set(obj.formMain,'Name','Rradioexample','NumberTitle','off',...
                  'MenuBar','none','Resize','Off');
              % a menu for exit the program            
              obj.menuFile.main = uimenu('Label','File');            
              obj.menuFile.exit = uimenu(obj.menuFile.main,...
                  'Label','Exit','Callback',{@obj.close_Callback,obj});
              % radiobutton to select the mode
              obj.radiogroup = uibuttongroup(obj.formMain,...
                  'Visible','on',...
                  'Units','pixels',...
                  'BackGroundColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8],...
                  'Position',[220 80 100 100]);
                  %'SelectionChangedFcn',@obj.bselection);
              uicontrol(obj.radiogroup,...
                  'Style',...
                  'radiobutton',...
                  'BackGroundColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8],...
                  'String','Option 1',...
                  'Position',[10 70 70 20],...
                  'Callback',@obj.opt1_Callback,...
                  'HandleVisibility','off');
              uicontrol(obj.radiogroup,...
                  'Style',...
                  'radiobutton',...
                  'BackGroundColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8],...
                  'String','Option 2',...
                  'Position',[10 50 70 20],...
                  'Callback',@obj.opt2_Callback,...
                  'HandleVisibility','off');    
              obj.buttonTest = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Print radiostaus intop the Command Window',...
                  'Position',[40,200,260,60],...
                  'Callback',{@obj.test_Callback,obj,'test'},'Enable','On');
              set(obj.formMain,'Visible','on');
              fprintf('programm started');
          end

          function opt1_Callback(~,hObject,evt)
              fprintf('switched to radio1 mode\n');
              obj.option1selcted = true;
          end
          function opt2_Callback(~,hObject,evt)
              fprintf('switched to radio2 mode\n');
              %msgbox('switched to radio2 mode','Success');
              obj.option1selcted = false;
          end
          function test_Callback(~,~,~,obj,val)
              fprintf('the status of the radiobutton is: %d\n', obj.option1selcted);
          end

      end
      methods(Static,Access=private)            
          function close_Callback(~,~,obj)  
              % close window
              close(obj.f)
          end

      end
      methods(Access=public,Hidden)
          function disp(obj)
          end
      end
  end
```

Comment: To work correctly it has to be changed to:
`function opt1_Callback(obj,hObject,evt)
              fprintf('switched to radio1 mode\n');
              obj.option1selcted = true; 
end`